# count all divs until the end of the dom with same class after a certain class(inc nested divs)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK I have the following dom tree:

```
    <div class="daterow">
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="daterow">
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="class1">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="daterow">
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="daterow">
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <div class="date">TEST CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

and i am trying to count all the divs with a class of date after the div with a class of class1, how do i go about this either in jquery or vanilla js here's what i have so far but I'm failing, fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dXGw3/1/

Comment: Is it within `daterow`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
$('.date').on('click', function () {
    var divs = $('div');
    var $findchckin = $('.class1');
    var index = divs.index($findchckin);
    divs.filter(':gt(' + index + ').date').addClass('aftercheckin');
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dXGw3/2/)**

If your `.daterow`s are within a container on the real page, you would probably want to use that container as the context for `divs`, for performance.

Comment: thank you very much that is exactly what i need, i actually have another class i need to select only it works like a charm accepted as soon as i can!!

Answer (score 0):

This works:
http://jsfiddle.net/dXGw3/9/

```
$(function() {
    $('.daterow > .class1').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).nextAll('.date').length);
    });
});
```

Comment: The number should be much more than 9, OP wants next cousins as well - check @kalley's answer